# How generic subtype and wildcards work in Collections.copy?

Tags: java, generics, collections

This is Collections copy method(part of it) :

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
   for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
     dst.set(i, src.get(i));
   }
}
```

There are 4 sample call :

```
List<Object> objs = Arrays.<Object>asList(2, 3.14, "four");
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(5, 6);

1. Collections.copy(objs, ints);
2. Collections.<Object>copy(objs, ints);
3. Collections.<Number>copy(objs, ints);
4. Collections.<Integer>copy(objs, ints);
```

***How above call works ?***

We could also declare the method with several possible signatures

```
1. public static <T> void copy(List<T> dst, List<T> src)
2. public static <T> void copy(List<T> dst, List<? extends T> src)
3. public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<T> src)
4. public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src)
```

For the example calls above,

- the first of these is too restrictive, as it only permits calls when
  the destination and source have exactly the same type. **(Understood)**.
- the second signature works only when the type parameter is Object
- the third signature works only when the type parameter is Integer
- the last signature works  for all three type parameters—i.e., Object,
  Number, and Integer.

***Please explain the second, third and last signatures too ?***

> The remaining three are equivalent for calls that use 
>   implicit type parameters, but differ for explicit type parameters.

What does this above statement means ?

Answer (score 6):

Let's consider each of your signature one by one.

```
1. public static <T> void copy(List<T> dst, List<? extends T> src)
```

If you invoke this method without explicit type parameter, the type parameter will be inferred as `Object`, as you are passing `List<Object>` as first argument. And then `List<? extends Object>` can accept an `Integer`.

However, if you invoke with explicit type argument `Number`, although you can pass a `List<Integer>` to `List<? extends Number>`, the same is not true for `List<Object>` and `List<Number>`, as generics are invariant.

```
2. public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<T> src)
```

Again for implicit type parameter, `T` will be inferred as `Integer`, as you are passing `List<Integer>` as 2nd argument to `List<T>`. And then `List<Object>` is a valid substitute for `List<? super Integer>`.

If you invoke the method with explicit type argument `Number`, you can pass `List<Object>` as 1st argument, but you can't pass `List<Integer>` as 2nd argument. For the same reason explained above.

```
3. public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src)
```

Now, this method signature will work for any type. For whatever type parameter being inferred, `dst` is consumer of `T` instance, whereas `src` is producer of `T` instance. For e.g., if you invoke with explicit type argument `Number`, then `List<Object>` is capture convertible to `List<? super Number>`, similarly, `List<Integer>` is capture convertible to `List<? extends Number>`. So, both the arguments are valid substitution.

So, in all the 3 cases, compiler can correctly infer the type parameters if you don't provide one explicitly. But you should use the 4th signature here for the reason being -

- `dst` is *consumer* of `T` instance, so it should use lower bounds, and
- `src` is *producer* of `T` instance, so it should use upper bounds.

---

**Related Post:**

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1679863)

**Reference:**

- [JLS - Capture Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)
- [Java Generics FAQs - What is a bounded wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20a%20bounded%20wildcard?)

Comment: "But you should use the 4th signature here" Why opt for a more complicated signature when a simpler one will also always work?

Comment: @newacct. I already explained that other alternatives won't work with explicit type arguments. And you don't know whether that method is going to be called with or without explicit type argument.

Comment: It does work with explicit type arguments, if you have the *right* explicit type argument. If you pick an explicit type argument that is wrong for that signature and arguments, then that's not the signature's problem.

Comment: @newacct. Well your argument is perfectly valid. But that also depends upon what that method is going to do. Given that this one is copy method. One list is consumer and other one is producer, so it is perfectly acceptible to use lower bounds and upper bounds here.